# Add user to group inside Docker container

Tags: docker

How do I make sure a Docker user is added to a specific group when running a container?

This is my situation. I'm running a Docker container where i need to access /dev/video0 which is owned by "root" and in group "video" on the host.

My host UID is 1000 and gid=1000 and I'm in the "video" group (gid=44). When I run the following Docker run command, the user with gid=1000 inside the container isn't added to the video group. I have to execute a command inside the container to add the user to the video group and then everything works.

```
docker run \
  --name=cloud9 \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=US/Eastern \
  -p 8000:8000 \
  -v /home/pi/code:/code `#optional` \
  --group-add 44 \
  --device=/dev/video0 \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  linuxserver/cloud9
```

How do I add user with uid=1000 to group 44 ('video') directly from the run command?

Comment: I have proposed a solution to this problem using vscode's devcontainers: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7722 if the issue can get enough up votes then maybe it will be implemented

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker run \
  --name=cloud9 \
  --user=1000:44 \   
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=US/Eastern \
  -p 8000:8000 \
  -v /home/pi/code:/code `#optional` \
  --group-add 44 \
  --device=/dev/video0 \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  linuxserver/cloud9
```

Comment: Thanks I tried and it results in an error. I think this is just the way this particular container manages users. I may ask this question in the linuxserver forum.